# How can I apply a Gaussian blur to a figure in `matplotlib`?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing, scipy

How can I apply a Gaussian blur to a figure in `matplotlib`?

To be more specific, I have the following image plotted in a `matplotlib` figure:

[image]

Which was produced with the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter


x = np.linspace(0, 3*np.pi, 100)
ys = []
for i in range(20):
    ys.append(np.sin(x) + (np.random.rand(100)-0.5)*np.random.rand())

new_y = ys[0]
new_x = x
for i in range(1, 20):
    new_x = np.concatenate([new_x, x])
    new_y = np.concatenate([new_y, ys[i]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist2d(new_x, new_y, bins=50, cmap='inferno')
plt.show()
```

How can I plot a Gaussian blurred version of this image? Any help would be appreciated.

---

### What I've tried:

I've tried grabbing the data from the figure before actually showing it, transforming it into a numpy array, applying the gaussian blur to the numpy array, and then plotting the blurred array using `plt.imshow`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter


x = np.linspace(0, 3*np.pi, 100)
ys = []
for i in range(20):
    ys.append(np.sin(x) + (np.random.rand(100)-0.5)*np.random.rand())

new_y = ys[0]
new_x = x
for i in range(1, 20):
    new_x = np.concatenate([new_x, x])
    new_y = np.concatenate([new_y, ys[i]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist2d(new_x, new_y, bins=50, cmap='inferno')
fig.canvas.draw()

data = np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8, sep='')
data = data.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))
data2 = gaussian_filter(data, sigma=5)


plt.imshow(data2)

plt.pause(5)
```

However, this apparently has no effect whatsoever in the produced image.

Comment: Don't call `ax.hist2d`, and use `np.hiostogram2d`, as suggested below, and then apply the blur to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of Markus' answer I managed to solve the problem. Using the `gaussian_filter` function on the data returned by `np.histogram2d` correctly applies the blur to the image:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter

x = np.linspace(0, 3*np.pi, 200)
xs = []
ys = []

for i in range(200):
    xs.append(x+np.random.rand(200))
    ys.append(np.sin(xs[i]) + (np.random.rand(200)-0.5)*np.random.rand())

new_y = ys[0]
new_x = xs[0]
for i in range(1, 200):
    new_x = np.concatenate([new_x, xs[i]])
    new_y = np.concatenate([new_y, ys[i]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = np.histogram2d(new_x, new_y, bins=150)[0]
data = gaussian_filter(data, sigma=5)
plt.pcolormesh(data.T, cmap='inferno', shading='gouraud')
fig.canvas.draw()

plt.pause(5)
```

Which generates the following image:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can plot the histogram with `pcolormesh` and use `shading="gouraud"`.  This might not be really Gaussian, but I think the result looks like what you are searching for, [see the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YIxO.png).

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 3*np.pi, 100)
ys = []
for i in range(20):
    ys.append(np.sin(x) + (np.random.rand(100)-0.5)*np.random.rand())

new_y = ys[0]
new_x = x
for i in range(1, 20):
    new_x = np.concatenate([new_x, x])
    new_y = np.concatenate([new_y, ys[i]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = np.histogram2d(new_x, new_y, bins=50)[0]
plt.pcolormesh(data.T, cmap='inferno', shading='gouraud')
fig.canvas.draw()

plt.pause(5)
```

Comment: This is indeed close to the end result I'm aiming for. However, I don't see a way to control how much blurring to apply to the image.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that, when you grab the rendered histogram, each bin has many pixels, and therefore smoothing that image is barely noticeable. Increasing the smoothing parameter should improve your results. But it will never look the way you expect because each input bin is a patch of pixels.

The proper solution would be to use [`numpy.histogram2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) to generate the histogram. You can then properly smooth it and display it any way you want.